# stop ie from closing when draging out a shortcut

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, tabs, internet-explorer-9

I mostly use Firefox but at work all their stuff is setup to use IE and I can't change that. so I'm stuck with using IE and I've noticed one uber annoying thing it does.

so I've got several tabs open doing various things in them in, one of the tabs has a site I wanted to create a shortcut on the desktop to. I'm used to being able to just drag that link out to the desktop and keep working on my stuff when I use Firefox at home this works great, but not so on IE.

I do know it will let me drag out the link and make a shortcut that isn't my problem; what is that IE will then close ALL the other tabs I have open with out asking and then reopen just the one tab that I dragged out. so annoying as now I gotta go and reopen all the other tabs I had going and that is just a pain in the ass. if I try to do the same thing on Chrome or Firefox it will just make the link and leave all my other tabs alone, how can I get IE to also do that??

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+drag the tab instead (simple drag-and-drop creates pinned site shortcuts instead of internet shortcuts).
2. File menu (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> if it's not visible) > Send > Shortcut to desktop.
3. Right-click the page > Create Shortcut.